# Scrapy - allow media pipeline to download already downloaded urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using a media pipeline to download various files to disk but it appears to be preventing downloads for previously downloaded files (with the same url). I'd prefer it not to do this, I would like the duplicate images to be downloaded (they are written with different filenames). Is there some way I can override this behaviour and allow the media pipeline to process the same url?

(using scrapy 0.24)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked throught the classes used in the media pipeline and it appears that a finger print of any media request is mae to avoid downloading duplicates.

In [scrapy/scrapy/utils/request.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/request.py) the request_fingerprint method describes creating a sha1 hash of the request including data such as request headers.

To allow duplicate requests I have included a piece of data unique to the item in a header value (to produce a unique finger print) like so:

```
def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    if isinstance(item, ExampleMedia):
        request = Request("http://example.com/medialibrary/"+str(item['mediaID']))
        request.meta['item'] = item
        request.headers['fpBuster']=item['uniqueID']
        yield request
```

I hope this helps anyone else looking for a way to download media duplicate requests. It would be nice if there was a way to do this without resorting to using headers like this as, I suppose, an unexpected header could have the potential to confuse target sites. If anyone has a better solution please let me know.